# Where is Component.deinitialize() called from?

Tags: codenameone

On iPhone, I frequently have null pointer exceptions in SwipeableContainer.close() due to getComponentForm returning null (see stacktrace below). I assume this means the SwipeListener has not been removed correctly which seems to happen in SwipeableContainer.deinitialize(). However, I cannot figure out from where deinitialize() is supposed to be called so I don't understand what I need to do to avoid this situation.

Any ideas?

```
     [EDT] 12:19:43,5 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null 
     java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com_codename1_ui_SwipeableContainer.close:199
       at com_codename1_ui_SwipeableContainer_SwipeListener.actionPerformed:437
       at com_codename1_ui_util_EventDispatcher.fireActionSync:459
       at com_codename1_ui_util_EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent:362
       at com_codename1_ui_Form.fireReleaseListeners:3770
       at com_codename1_ui_Form.pointerReleased:3847
       at com_codename1_ui_Component.pointerReleased:4710
       at com_codename1_ui_Display.handleEvent:2359
```

Answer (score 1):

deinitialize should be invoked on removal of the component or the form. But this can fail in this case if we have an event chain with multiple operation where a user action can trigger both the close and the removal.

The workaround is to wrap the second operation in a `callSerially` to postpone it to the next EDT cycle but for now I just added a fix to the null pointer exception in `close()` so the method won't fail if there's no parent `Form`.